# No block "form" found while rendering the form. in Symfony App outside controller in separate class

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

i try to create some kind of formbuilder that outputs html of generated forms using the symfony form extenstion (using all the nice stuff like valdation, error hightlighting and such).

is use symfony 5 with twig 3.0

the created class

```
class FormBuilder{
    private $twig;
    private $formFactory;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $defaultFormTheme = 'contact.html.twig';
    
        $loader = new FilesystemLoader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../template/forms');
        $this->twig = new Environment($loader, ['cache' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../var/cache/'.$_ENV['APP_ENV'].'/twig']);
    
        $formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine([$defaultFormTheme], $this->twig);

        $this->twig->addRuntimeLoader(new FactoryRuntimeLoader([
            FormRenderer::class => function () use ($formEngine) {
                return new FormRenderer($formEngine);
            },
        ]));
        $this->twig->addExtension(new FormExtension());

        $this->formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
            ->getFormFactory();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContactForm():string
    {
        $form = $this->formFactory->createBuilder()
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
            ->getForm();

        return $this->twig->render('contact.html.twig', [
            'contact_form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and call it somewhere else with

```
$fb = new FormBuilder();
var_dump($fb->getContactForm());
```

it doesn't matter if the template looks like

```
{{ form_start(contact_form) }}
    {{ form_widget(contact_form) }}
    <input type="submit"/>
{{ form_end(contact_form) }}
```

or

```
{{ form(contact_form) }}
```

there is always the and runtime error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No block "form" found while rendering the form.").

or in first template example instead of "form" it yells about "form_start".

searching for hours now, but seems i to blind to find the missing spot..
any suggestions or tips how to include the form function in twig outside the symfony controller?

Comment: you need `symfony/twig-bridge` and add the extension to your twig, specifically https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/FormExtension.php

Comment: i thought that was done by $this->twig->addExtension(new FormExtension());
is use the namespace Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension

do i have to implement it different?

Comment: oh, my error and my bad. In that case, you have to set a (default) form theme. Actually, I'm not quite sure how to do this in standalone library use, but a form theme has to be set, one of those here are available by default: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/5.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form syntax `{{ form_theme contact_form "form_div_layout.html.twig" }}` (in framework symfony, no idea how it would be in your case)

Comment: thanks, seems to work (a bit more) now.

now it only complains about the missing translation extensions that i don't use :p

when i got this fixed i post the whole solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with adding themes and (because of translation in the themes) translation it now works

```
public function __construct()
{
    // name of theme template
    $defaultFormTheme = 'form_div_layout.html.twig';

    $appVariableReflection = new \ReflectionClass('\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable');
    $vendorTwigBridgeDirectory = dirname($appVariableReflection->getFileName());

    //where the forms reside
    $viewsDirectory = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../template/forms');
    
    //init twig with directories
    $this->twig = new Environment(new FilesystemLoader([
        $viewsDirectory,
        $vendorTwigBridgeDirectory.'/Resources/views/Form',
    ]));
    
    //apply theme to twig/renderer
    $formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine([$defaultFormTheme], $this->twig);

    $this->twig->addRuntimeLoader(new FactoryRuntimeLoader([
        FormRenderer::class => function () use ($formEngine) {
            return new FormRenderer($formEngine);
        },
    ]));
    
    //add form extenstion
    $this->twig->addExtension(new FormExtension());

    // this is for the filter |trans
    $filter = new TwigFilter('trans', function ($context, $string) {
        return Translation::TransGetText($string, $context);
    }, ['needs_context' => true]);

    // load the i18n extension for using the translation tag for twig
    // {% trans %}my string{% endtrans %}
    $this->twig->addFilter($filter);
    $this->twig->addExtension(new Translation());

    //prepare factory for later use
    $this->formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
        ->getFormFactory();
}
```

just needs additional php extension 'gettext' and the translation extension for twig from https://github.com/JBlond/twig-trans (the original seems to support only twig up to v2.x)

thanks again Jakumi for the solving hint :)